# Multiplying Content of a Word File using Python and python-docx

Tags: python, tkinter, python-docx

I am in the midst of constructing a Python application leveraging the tkinter and python-docx libraries. Its purpose is to read an existing Word document (comprising of tables, paragraphs, and other typical Word elements) and reproduce its content a user-specified number of times within the same document. The quintessence of this endeavor is to generate printable labels for delivery purposes.

Objective:
The application should be able to:

Allow the user to select a .docx file.
Let the user specify the number of times the content should be duplicated.
Save the result with the original content reproduced the specified number of times.
Current State:
Utilizing the code below, I have managed to replicate the content. However, it appears that only the first page retains the original content, while the subsequent pages are bereft of it:

python
Copy code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from docx import Document

class WordMultiplierApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Word Content Multiplier')
        
        self.file_path = tk.StringVar()
        
        # UI components
        tk.Label(root, text="Select Word File:").pack(pady=10)
        tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=self.browse_file).pack(pady=10)
        
        tk.Label(root, text="No. of Times to Multiply:").pack(pady=10)
        self.multiplier = tk.Entry(root)
        self.multiplier.pack(pady=10)
        
        tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=self.process_file).pack(pady=20)

    def browse_file(self):
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Word Files', '*.docx')])
        if file:
            self.file_path.set(file)

    def process_file(self):
        if not self.file_path.get():
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a valid Word file.")
            return
        
        try:
            times = int(self.multiplier.get())
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Enter a valid integer for multiplication.")
            return
        
        original_doc = Document(self.file_path.get())

        # Check if original doc is not empty
        if not original_doc.paragraphs:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "The Word file seems empty or content cannot be read.")
            return

        # Multiply content of each paragraph
        paragraphs = list(original_doc.paragraphs)
        for para in paragraphs:
            original_text = para.text
            for _ in range(1, times):
                original_doc.add_paragraph(original_text)
                
        save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".docx", filetypes=[('Word Files', '*.docx')])
        if save_path:
            original_doc.save(save_path)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "File processed and saved successfully!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = WordMultiplierApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Challenge:
How can I ensure that the content is genuinely duplicated the specified number of times, including tables, paragraphs, and other elements, without any omission?

Any insights or solutions to this conundrum would be profoundly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Utilizing the python-docx library, I endeavored to iterate through each paragraph of the original document and append the text a user-defined number of times. My expectation was straightforward: for every paragraph, table, or other Word element in the original document, the content would be duplicated the exact number of times specified by the user, maintaining the original formatting and structure.

However, upon execution, I noticed an aberration. While the first page accurately replicated the content, subsequent pages were inexplicably devoid of it. Given the objective of generating printable labels, this inconsistency hinders the application's efficacy.

Edit after -- @timroberts :

Thank you for the feedback. I'm currently using the PyPDF2 library in Python for working with PDFs. Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
python
Copy code
import PyPDF2

def multiply_pdf_content(input_pdf, output_pdf, times):
    with open(input_pdf, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        for _ in range(times):
            for page_num in range(reader.numPages):
                page = reader.getPage(page_num)
                writer.addPage(page)

        with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as output_file:
            writer.write(output_file)
```

Despite attempting to multiply the content multiple times, I only get a single copy of the content in the output PDF. Any guidance on what I might be doing wrong would be really helpful.

Comment: You would be better served learning how to generate PDF files for this.  Word output is notoriously fickle and unreliable, whereas with PDF you have absolute control over the placement of the items on a page.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the suggestion. I've indeed transitioned to working with PDFs as per your advice. However, I'm currently facing an issue where the PDF is only copied once despite trying to multiply its content multiple times. I'm not sure about the right logic to achieve this. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's probably worth another question, since we don't know what PDF tools you're using.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your continued help . I've responded to your query in the main post by editing it. I added my response after "Edit after --  timroberts:" since the detailed response was too lengthy for a comment. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, but when I modify your code so that it matches the latest PyPDF2 API, it works just fine:

```
import PyPDF2

def multiply_pdf_content(input_pdf, output_pdf, times):
    with open(input_pdf, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

        for _ in range(times):
            for page in reader.pages:
                writer.add_page(page)

        with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as output_file:
            writer.write(output_file)

multiply_pdf_content('Video.pdf','xxx.pdf',5)
```